# For some reason I keep getting an index error even when the item is in the range

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I keep getting an index out of range error for this code? Even though there are clearly three items. It works when I put in 0 and -1 but not when I put in 1 into the split_age[1]. Am I missing something?

```
ages = []
for d in open_files:
    if len(d) >= 3:
        age = d[3]
        split_age = age.split(','[0:])
        ages.append(split_age[1])
print(ages)
```

Comment: when `d` is length 3, it won't have a 4th index

Comment: Print the split_age using `print (split_age)` before `ages.append...`and check the number of items in the list. This should give you a fair idea. I guess there is only one item hence it works with index = 0 and index = -1 and not with index = 1.

Comment: `python` uses 0 index method, so when `len(object)` is 3, it means it has `object[0], object[1], object[2]` sub-objects, but not `object[3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you haven't asked about, but could pop up later:

1. if `len(d) == 3`, then `d[3]` will try to access an element outside of `d`, namely its 4-th element and an `IndexError` will be thrown. If you'd like to access the last element, then `d[-1]` is what you're looking for. Otherwise just change the condition into `if len(d) > 3`.
2. The `','[0:]` in `age.split(','[0:])` is redundant, since `','[0:] == ','`.

To see why the you're getting the error when using `split_age[1]` consider what happens when there is no `','` in `age`. For example, say `age == "12.12"` then `age.split(',')` will return ["12.12"] -- an array with just one element. Thus trying to access *2nd* element with index 1 throws an `IndexError`. Finally, if `age` is an empty string, the same will happen `age.split(',')` will return an array with one element `['']` and trying to access its second element will fail. Thus you can be sure that as long as `age` is a string `split(',')` will return an array with at least one element (otherwise it would most likely throw an error anyway).

A solution for this is to either explicitly check the length of `split_age` or for the presence of the delimiter used in `split` (in your case ",") in `age`. Notice also, that the second would work even if `age == ','` as in that case `age.split(',')` will return an array with two elements (namely, two empty strings). Taking all this into account, your improved code could look something like this:

```py
ages = []
for d in open_files:
    if len(d) > 3:
        age = d[3]
        if ',' in age:
            split_age = age.split(',')
            ages.append(split_age[1])
print(ages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python uses 0 index, that means when your list or tuple have 3 item indexes are 0, 1, 2
same things when your list length is 10 the max index is 9
so d(3) printed out of range error because list haven't 4 item
I hope you understand my answer